# TypeOrm Problem Record Existing but return null

Tags: mysql, service, nestjs, typeorm

Goodmorning
I have a problem in my nestJs app. I use typeorm for find data on my db. this is my service method:

```
async findByIdentificativo(id: string): Promise<Evento> {
    console.log(id)
    const evento=await this.eventoRepository.findOneOrFail({
      where: {
        identificativo: id,
        partecipanti:{deletedAt: IsNull()}
      },
      relations: [
        'partecipanti',
        'campionato',
        'giudice',
        'impiantoLuogo',
        'impiantoLuogo.enteId',
        'impiantoLuogo.enteId.enteId',
        'disciplinaEvento',
        'disciplinaEvento.specialita',
        'disciplinaEvento.specialita.categorie',
        'partecipanti.associato',
        'partecipanti.associato.persona',
        'giudice.persona',
        'partecipanti.associato.indiceAssociato',
        'gareCategorie', 
        'gareCategorie.categoria',
        'gareCategorie.categoria.idSpecialita'
      ],
    });
    
    return await evento;
  }
```

Now this method works for almost the id i Use. But i have some Id that return null. Why?

I have tried to set the await in all the functions

Comment: did you try with {deletedAt: null}?

Comment: yes, the problem is not about the delete, i have tried without relations but the problem still persist

Comment: if your relationships are of the inner join type, it is necessary that there is a reference to the "evento" table in all related tables